# grunt-mocha: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call

Tags: phantomjs, mocha.js

I tried using grunt-mocha with requirejs, but I get this error:

```
Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.
```

If I try using the simplest example present on mochajs.org - it works, but for some reason not with requirejs.

Here are my files.

**test/browser/runner.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Browser test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="./../../bower_components/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="mocha"></div>

    <script data-main="runner.js" src="./../../bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**test/browser/runner.js:** (I tried multiple versions so far, this is the most recent, but still times out)

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: './../../',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
        'chai': 'bower_components/chai/chai',
        'mocha': 'bower_components/mocha/mocha'
    },
    shim: {}
});

define(function(require) {

    require('chai');
    require('mocha');

    mocha.setup('bdd');

    require([
        'test/src/test.component'
    ], function() {
        console.log('component success');
        mocha.run();
        console.log('mocha should be running');
    }, function() {
        console.log('component error');
    });

});
```

**test/src/test.component.js:**

```
define(function(require) {
    describe('Component', function() {
        it('test', function() {
            console.log('testing...');
        });
    });
});
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        mocha: {
            options: {
                reporter: 'Spec',
                log: true,
                run: true
            },
            src: ['./test/**/*.html']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-mocha');
};
```

The output is this:

```
$ grunt mocha
Running "mocha:src" (mocha) task
Testing: ./test/browser/runner.html
component success
mocha should be running
testing...

Warning: PhantomJS timed out, possibly due to a missing Mocha run() call. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

so I'm pretty sure there are no syntactical errors and it should work. I'm probably just having a brain fart :)

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem -- I solved it with the `grunt-mocha-test` plugin. I changed the task naming in the `grunt` file to `mochaTest`, and installed `grunt-mocha-test` with:

```
npm install grunt-mocha-test --save-dev
```

Now it's working.